# How can I convert the items in the list into a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I have this function I created which takes the contents of the file and translates it into a dictionary. I have the correct format, I just cannot seem to figure out how to make the list contents into a tuple.

Here is my function to do that, which doesn't have the tuple part down:

```
def read(file:open) -> dict:
    file_lines = file.read().splitlines()
    result_dict = dict()
    for string in file_lines:
        splitted = string.replace(':', ';')
        new_splitted = splitted.split(';')
        client_name = new_splitted[0]
        new_splitted = new_splitted[1:]
        result_dict[client_name] = new_splitted
    return result_dict
```

For example, how can i make the it a tuple? I tried using tuple(), ((x,)), and nothing seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: `tuple(x.split(','))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use construct tuple with `tuple(sequence)`.

```
with open("portfolio1.txt", 'r') as f:
    d = dict()
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        key, prevalue = line.split(':')
        d[key] = [tuple(item.split(',')) for item in prevalue.split(';')]
    print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way you can structure your logic. This method also deals with string to integer conversion.

```
def splitter(item):
    split = item.split(',')
    return (split[0], int(split[1]), int(split[2]))

d = {}

with open('portfolio1.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        k, vals = line.rstrip().split(':')
        v = [splitter(x) for x in vals.split(';')]
        d[k] = v
```

Result:

```
{'Alan': [('Intel', 20, 10),
          ('Dell', 10, 50),
          ('Apple', 80, 80),
          ('Dell', -10, 55)],
 'Barb': [('Intel', 20, 40),
          ('Intel', -10, 45),
          ('IBM', 40, 30),
          ('Intel', -10, 35)],
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas`. Just make sure to replace all `:` for `;` before.

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep = ";", header = None)
df.set_index(0).apply(lambda k: [tuple(str(j).split(",")) for j in k], 1).T.to_dict(orient="list")

{'Alan': [('Intel', '20', '10'),
  ('Dell', '10', '50'),
  ('Apple', '80', '80'),
  ('Dell', '-10', '55')],
 'Barb': [('Intel', '20', '40'),
  ('Intel', '-10', '45'),
  ('IBM', '40', '30'),
  ('Intel', '-10', '35')],
 'Carl': [('Intel', '30', '40'),
  ('Dell', '20', '50'),
  ('Intel', '-10', '60'),
  ('Apple', '20', '55')],
 'Dawn': [('Apple', '40', '80'),
  ('Apple', '40', '85'),
  ('Apple', '-40', '90'),
  ('nan',)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change like below ,

### Use tuple(x.split(,))

```
def read_db(file:open) -> dict:
    file_lines = file.read().splitlines()
    result_dict = dict()
    for string in file_lines:
        splitted = string.split(':')
        client_name = splitted[0]
        new_splitted = splitted[1]
        parts = new_splitted.split(';')
        # tuple(x.split(','))
        parts_tuple = [tuple(x.split(',')) for x in parts]
        result_dict[client_name] = parts_tuple
```

### Output

```
{
    'Carl': [('Intel', '30', '40'), ('Dell', '20', '50'), ('Intel', '-10', '60'), ('Apple', '20', '55')],
    'Barb': [('Intel', '20', '40'), ('Intel', '-10', '45'), ('IBM', '40', '30'), ('Intel', '-10', '35')],
    'Alan': [('Intel', '20', '10'), ('Dell', '10', '50'), ('Apple', '80', '80'), ('Dell', '-10', '55')],
    'Dawn': [('Apple', '40', '80'), ('Apple', '40', '85'), ('Apple', '-40', '90')]
}
```

Comment: how can i make it so that the integer values are ints and not strings? for example instead of '30', i want 30

Comment: use `splitter` like jpp's answer

Comment: how can I incorporate that into your changed solution? I feel like it changes too much

Comment: `parts_tuple = [splitter(x) for x in parts]` instead of `parts_tuple = [tuple(x.split(',')) for x in parts]` otherwise its better to use jpp's solution